# System without /tmp dir?

Tags: filesystem, files, 15.10, tmp

Running `df -h` gives:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           385M  6.2M  379M   2% /run
/dev/sda2       113G   27G   81G  25% /
tmpfs           1.9G   69M  1.9G   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       511M  3.4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           385M   40K  385M   1% /run/user/1000
```

so no `/tmp` is showing up. What is going on here?

Comment: Please provide the source of that block of text (probably a command).

Comment: You can see `/tmp` dir if you use more appropriate command for this: `ls /`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That is not a list of directories.  That is a list of filesystems.

`/tmp` would only show up in this list if your `/tmp` was a mount point for a separate filesystem, rather than a directory.

You don't need `/tmp` to be a separate filesystem.  There are various reasons some people or pre-configured systems sometimes do this, but it's not mandatory and it's a choice.  In particular, some people run `/tmp` as a tmpfs filesystem.  The performance benefits of this are debatable, and it can have drawbacks.  Unless you have specific requirements that make having `/tmp` as a regular directory in your root filesystem inappropriate, my recommendation is to stick with what you have.

Comment: having /tmp a separate filesystem has a BIG advantage: you won't fill up the entire root filesystem if you fill up /tmp. But it has a drawback: /tmp may end up being too small, sometimes (and the space underused most of the time). Therefore it happens that it is not in a separated filesystem (and therefore in the root (/) filesystem) if you can live with (or prevent) the potential problem of filling / . Monitoring most filesystems fill % is a good idea (ex: have warnings when one fills >=80% of space or inodes). Having either "/" or "/tmp" fill up is often bad, with lots of weird consequences

Comment: That's true. Note that the default filesystems have that feature where non-root processes can't fill up the last 5% of the drive, which means that once this is "full", user processes will not be able to write files but there is still enough space for the system to boot, start services, write logs, etc and you can repair the problem without the weird stuff happening.  Root processes that run on their own should never fill the drive in a normal setup, even if your root partition is pretty small ie a couple of hundred MB - there's complex log rotation mechanisms in your system to prevent this.

Comment: @thomasrutter: about the 5% limit: it is true for process run under other users than root, but process run as root are still able to fill up the remaining 5% ^^ [they shouldn't, of course... but Stuff Happens]